# How to generate a unique fake email with a custom domain with faker?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I have a laravel application that requires the registered users must use their company email (custom domain).

So how i can i achieve that with faker generators to test it with my model factories ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a simple trick with php's `preg_replace` function:

`preg_replace('/@example\..*/', '@domain.com', $faker->unique()->safeEmail)`

so your laravel model factory might looks like this:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => preg_replace('/@example\..*/', '@domain.com', $faker->unique()->safeEmail),
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'avatar' => $faker->imageUrl,
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Faker\Generator* to create an auxiliary variables:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $userName = $faker->userName;
    $uniqueSuffix = $faker->unique()->word;
    $domain = 'your.domain.com';
    $uniqueFakeEmail = "$userName.$uniqueSuffix@$domain";

    return [
        'email' => $uniqueFakeEmail,
        // ...
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be something like

```
$email = $faker->userName().'@mydomain.com';
```